# How to display a division over other element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a div over a image. When user enters the image the division must display, means on hover effect. But what happens is when I hover the mouse over main division the div displayed under the image.

My code is :

```
 <div class="bgimg">
 <img width="100%" height="100%" data-id="1" src="data:image/jpeg;">
 <div id="changeBackPicture" style="display: none;"> 
  <a id="ChangeBAKPicture" href="javascript:void(0)">Change BackGround Picture</a>
 </div>     <-- This division need to display above the image --->
 <div class="primg"></div>
 <div id="uname">xyz </div>
 </div>
```

css code :

```
#changeBackPicture
{
float:right;
margin-top:-70px;
margin-right:500px;
width:270px;
height:35px;
margin-left:-3px;
margin-right:-3px;
}
```

Below picture shows how the division now displaying. I need to display the division over the image...
[image]

Please anyone tell me how to do this stuff........ Thanks. ...

Comment: try `#changeBackPicture { position: relative; z-index: 9999;}`

Comment: @Eric Lemos Thank you for your reply. Actually I don't know about `z-index`. But it worked...

Comment: moved comment to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

z-index is a CSS property that sets the stack order of specific elements. An element with greater stack order is always in front of another element with lower stack order.

In order for the element to use z-index, it must have be positioned absolute, relative, or fixed.

```
#changeBackPicture { position: relative; z-index: 9999;}
```

**resource: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp**

Answer (score 2):

It really isn't all that complicated, you should have a look at the [Z Index CSS Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) as that does exactly what you require.

Make sure you set the Z index for both the image you are trying to cover and the div you are covering it with!

Comment: Also, realize that you need to explicitly state the element's positioning as well.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding a z-index to your overlay div?
give it a z-index of 50 and see if that works. 
You can also give it absolute positioning and just place it ontop of the image div.